# Retrieving the data from a list in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have private `List<Product> mCartList;` in my activity. When I debug I got some values for `mCartList`, I have shown them in below screen shot.

[image]

Now I want to get that inside the `mCartList`, so I have tried the below code. I;m getting an error saying `Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression` at each line of my code. Whats the mistake I have made when retrieving the data out of `mCartList`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mCartList.size(); i++) {
            mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
            mCartList.get(i).crust;
            mCartList.get(i).description;
```

It will be really great if anyone could correct me.

**UPDATED**

[image]

Comment: Your code gives error for this two line

mCartList.get(i).crust;
            mCartList.get(i).description;

Comment: @Avishek Das yes. What is the mistake I have made there? Can you spot it?

Comment: it wouldn't be easier to make for ( Product item : mCartList) , I can't dubug it right now, but my solution comes automatically to my mind. Then you can take item inside loop and do whatever you want. Like { item.selected = false; }. I'm also curios what you want to do by doing mCartlist.get(i).crust ? you need to assign it to some variable or assign something to crust variable

Comment: What you want to do actually?

Comment: I want to display the value of crust and description, so I'm trying to get these 2 data out of mCartList.

Comment: Where you want to display?

Comment: You have assign it in wrong way the line: ' mCartList.get(i).selected = false;' is the incorrect line. You cant assign like this. Now what exactly you want to do? Your saying you got data from mCartList and in opposite you are saying you want the data in mCartList

Comment: You can display it in toast Toast.makeText(Activity.this, mCartList.get(i).crust, Toast.LONG).show();

Comment: I have a list view in that I have 2 textviews, In that I want to show crust is this, and description is this like that. In the screen shot it shows chicken for description. I want to take that value and disaply in the textview

Comment: @Clairvoyant no problem with that line. Issue is with other lines. I never said I want to have these data in mCartList. I have another listview

Comment: Can you show your whole code, where you take one item of listView and you put data inside ?

Comment: @modabeckham see the data which you want to fetch the crust has null value.

Comment: @Clairvoyant is because I didn't put a value for crust. I can't run the code because it has the error I mentioned in the question

Comment: @MyWay I'm in the 1st stage still. I'm trying to get the data out of mCartList and pass it to adapter.

Comment: I want to know how can I get the value out of mCartList and display in a textview. This is how I work when I get data from json response I need similarly how can I do for a list.( for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
    final JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i); )

Comment: This two lines looks weird for me mCartList.get(i).crust;
            mCartList.get(i).description; , as error says you need to Complete Expression, try for example to be sure if data are correct, show it in logcat by Log.i("mCart crust", mCartList.get(i).crust);  Log.i("mCart description", mCartList.get(i).description); , this shouldn't produce error. In your code you took the valus and don't make with them nothing. You can assign it to another variables as well.

Comment: @ MyWay  Can u tell me how to do You can assign it to another variables as well as u said

Comment: Hi... where do you set "crust" and "description" ? can we have log cat or your code snippet ?

Comment: can u check the updated screen shot please. toast and Log.i both works

Comment: for example String crustString; for (int i = 0; i < mCartList.size(); i++) { //you should also check if the values are not empt and not null if(mCartList.get(i).crust != null && !mCartList.get(i).crust.isEmpty(){
           
           crustString =  mCartList.get(i).crust;// do smth with crustStrting   }}

Comment: nice to hear it, gl with project